# How to debug troubles with unix domain sockets?

Tags: linux, networking, socket

Ubuntu Server 10.04.2

```
$ uname -a
Linux my.local 2.6.32-30-generic-pae #59-Ubuntu SMP 
Tue Mar 1 23:01:33 UTC 2011 i686 GNU/Linux
```

It seems that my domain socket queue is overflowing, but I can't prove it.

I've got this stack `nginx->[spawn-fcgi->multiwatch->]custom-fcgi-service`

Nginx is communicating with `custom-fcgi-service` by the means of unix domain socket.

Today we've got slight increase in traffic, and suddenly my nginx `error.log` is full of eels:

```
2011/04/07 15:31:51 [error] 28187#0: *469350 connect() to unix:/tmp/my.socket 
failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream, 
client: [IP witheld], server: my.local, request: "GET /myurl HTTP/1.0", 
upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/tmp/my.socket:", host: "example.com"
```

Some requests make it through, but many return 5xx error.

If I restart `custom-fcgi-service`, error goes away, but soon enough reappears. After inspecting `custom-fcgi-service` status, I'm reasonably sure that it works OK (though may be too slow for this amount of traffic, but that is a mere hypothesis).

I've tried doing this:

```
echo 65535 > /proc/sys/net/unix/max_dgram_qlen
```

But it did not help much. (Not sure if time-to-error became longer, may be, but not enough to fix it.)

If I increase number of worker forks of `custom-fcgi-service`, error does not appear for longer time, but so far I was not able to increase number of workers high enough to fix it for ever. CPU and memory and IO load on that machine are well within limits, so, again, I think that `custom-fcgi-service` is just being slow on some subsequent network call.

Question is: how to debug this issue? And if it is indeed socket queue length, how to make a sensor that will warn us that we need to fork more `custom-fcgi-service` workers?

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you have problem with connect, not with send. Try to increase kernel receiver backlog:

```
echo "2000" > /proc/sys/net/core/netdev_max_backlog
```

or

```
sysctl –w sys.net.core.netdev_max_backlog=2000
```

Have you checked system logs (e.g. dmesg)?

Comment: `$ cat /proc/sys/net/core/netdev_max_backlog` `40000` (i.e. it seems to be high enough already)

Comment: `dmesg` is silent since boot.

Comment: Look at `/proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn` option. Default value is 128, you should set it to at least 2000.

Comment: `$ cat /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn` `262144`

Answer (score -3):

try to change spawn's configuration file, backlog: 4096.