# Trying to find bottleneck... 60k onsite visitors

Tags: nginx, php, performance, wordpress, php-fpm

I know this will be hard, but I'm willing to try the Q&A route.

I have a Wordpress site that currently has 60,000 visitors on the site at once.

I'm using an EC2 `m3.xlarge`, `php/php-fpm 5.5.10`, `nginx 1.4.7`, `php-apc`.

For caching plugin I'm using WP-Super-Cache.

I'm noticing a very slow response time, lots of `502` errors, plus... I have tons of errors like these in my nginx log:

`10319#0: *57132 connect() to unix:/tmp/php5-fpm.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream`

I'm confused what the heck the bottle neck is...

- I have 4 CPU cores, each at about ~15%... total load avg of .85-1 constant
- ~4GB used of 16GB
- RDS at 60% CPU usage, low latency for reads and writes

For my settings... ive basically exhausted all my knowledge + hours of googling...

- 100 max_children for php-fpm
- 4096 for backlog & somaxconn
- nginx: worker_rlimit_nofile  200000
- nginx: worker_processes  8
- nginx: worker_connections  32768

I don't know if some of these are too high or low, I've tried to tweak it to the best of my ability...

I don't even really know how to find the problem either. When I look through slow log it's just a lot of random stuff probably because *everything* is going slow... not just one thing.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/q/256797/126632

Comment: I already tried that (see my bullet list). Both are at 4096

Comment: Apparently it needs to be much larger. And anyway, you should be scaling out, not up.

Comment: interesting.. ok

Comment: as for scaling out... yes I know, the syncing cache files and stuff is not fun for me... i guess its that time though :(

Answer (score 1):

Some monitoring and graphing tool would be useful to pinpoint the location of bottleneck. We use http://munin-monitoring.org/  Munin grabs stats from most of known services plus system metrics and it works almost out-of-the-box on modern distros.

Answer (score 1):

I think `pm.max_children = 100` is way too small for 60k concurrent visitors. Even if a visitor clicks a link only once in a minute on average then you'd need to generate 1000 page views in a second (`60000/60`).

You have 12GB of unused memory — set for example `pm.max_children = 500`. Maybe even higher - depending how much RAM is needed to generate an average request. Observe RAM usage and tune number on children accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

You are using 8 nginx worker_processes 8 when you only have 4 cores? I'd suggest using 3 and then allowing the remaining cpu core for other machine tasks.